# Copy table and add new first column with value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mariadb, create-table

I would like to create a MySQL table with new column with value. The following is the original table:

```
Column A B C
Value1 1 2 3
Value2 4 5 6
```

After copy, the new table would be like this, with new column in the beginning of the table:

```
Column A' A B C
Value1 1  1 2 3
Value2 1  4 5 6
```

Since the new column is the first column and filled with value instead of NULL, I cannot just insert everything from or create like old table. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Where does the new column's value come from? Is it always `1`?

Comment: The value of new column is assigned by myself during copy

Comment: The more important question is whether it's the same for every row. If not, how is the code that does the copy supposed to know what it is for each row?

Comment: Yes. The new column will have same value for every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the new value as a literal in a `SELECT` statement that gets the data from the old table.

```
CREATE TABLE newTable ( /* column specifications here */ ) AS
SELECT 1, oldTable.*
FROM oldTable
```

Comment: The column specifications are not needed if you use `1 as Aprime` or something similar.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I originally wrote that, but then decided it would be a poor idea to let the datatype of the new column default.

Comment: . . I think the default is fine, at least for the base type, because it would be the same as in the old table (of course nullability wouldn't transfer).